# Dialog box or form where user can choose to enter details or cancel

Tags: android, dialog

Within my application I would like to have a dialog box or a form appear to the user which allows the user to enter their name and telephone number.

I cannot see anything available for the user to enter details on a pop up form or dialog box. Is there any easy way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also stick a layout into an alert dialog using an AlertDialog.Builder, like so:

```
    //Preparing views
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
//layout_root should be the name of the "top-level" layout node in the dialog_layout.xml file.
    final EditText nameBox = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.name_box);
    final EditText phoneBox = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.phone_box);

    //Building dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(layout);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            //save info where you want it
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

Comment: This is basically taken from here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html. Good source also for other variations.

Comment: And how did you get the EditText info?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a [Custom Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) using any layout you want.